# Emacs not active when switching from different workspace

Tags: cursor

this repulses me to my core. Every so often when I switch to my emacs from a different workspace (awesome wm) the cursor appears just as an outlined box and is not active until I switch back and forth between workspaces a second time. What is this behaviour and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you reproduce this from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: What @Basil said. Provide a more complete, step-by-step recipe to reproduce your problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: problem is that this issue does only occur irregularly, so it is hard to reproduce the bug, which I am not certain is related to emacs in the first place...